# Certain characters (em and n dashes) are breaking during CSV import

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I wrote a CSV import tool. Here's a sample CSV as written in NP++. Note that the CSV is pipe delimited:

[image: sample csv]

However, when I run through with the debugger, I'm seeing broken characters instead of my em and en dashes:

[image]

Here's a snippet of relevant code. It's working how I want it to, minus messing up certain characters. Do I need to open or read the file a different way?

```
Item community = NodeHelper.GetChildrenByProperty(parentItem, "OUNumber", ouNumber).FirstOrDefault();
List<string> csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text).ToList();
foreach (string line in csvLines)
{
  List<string> components = line.Split('|').ToList();
  ...
  if (community != null)
  {
    components.Remove(components.First());
    community.Editing.BeginEdit();
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldIDs.Count(); i++)
    {
        string value = components.Skip(i).First();
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = String.Empty;
        }
        ....
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you wanting to left trim and right trim or trim all empty spaces when splitting the file..? you could do something like this
`IEnumerable<string[]> allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@txtFilePath.Text).Select(x => x.Split('|'));` then from there you can store into a Class or a Datatable etc..

Comment: What's the encoding of your csv file? You may want to specify the encoding when reading your file: [File.ReadAllLines Method (String, Encoding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, have you considered using [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Filburt I'm actually not sure of the encoding on the file. Is there a way I can view it?

Comment: NP++ should tell you in the status bar (bottom right). My bet is on "UTF-8 w/o BOM".